# Why does my Selenium Automation test suite fails intermittently?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My test suite fails intermittently throwing error as 'Element not found' even after putting all sort of waits(waitForPageLoad , Thread.sleep and explicit wait for element to be loaded in a page)  it fails intermittently.

When running the same test case individually runs fine and also sometimes along with n number of test cases it works fine.There is no consistency to which test case will fail when I try running the full automation test suite consisting of 30 to 40 test cases.

Can anyone please help me to find the root cause for the same.

I am running the test suite through maven in following phase:

```
<executions><execution>         
 <phase>site</phase>            
   <goals>              
      <goal>send-mail</goal>            
   </goals>     
</execution> </executions>
```

Does it have any relation in which Maven phase am running ?

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm seeing similar behavior in selenium's webdriver JS & chromedriver. Suite consistently failed at a particular test until I updated the selenium and chromedriver versions, now it still fails but a few tests down the list. Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Maven, but you are waiting for the page to load but that doesn't necessarily mean that the element you want has loaded.

I think you need to be certain that the element you wanted was actually present, and if it was present, was it interactive.

You say you are using Thread.sleep() but this will only wait a specific period of time without any intelligence regarding the presence of elements on a page.

What you should be doing is polling for an element to become avaialable. Try looking at Explicit Waits http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Here you combine two elements WebDriverWait and ExpectedCondition so that you wait until the element is clickable for up to say 30 seconds then fail.

Also you say that the test runs fine in isolation but poorly in a run. This tells me that you aren't resetting your environment to a good known state. A simple example would be closing your browser after each test and a better way would be to fire up an immutable VM (or docker container) for each test case so that you get the same thing over and over again.

Although there are cases where you would want to not do that and see how your tests handle a soak.

Getting stable and reproducible though should be your main concern. Have a look at when the test fails and confirm that the element you wanted was actually available at that particular time. Memory leaks etc.. can slow the browser down and make a sleep of 3 seconds more like 20. If you are going to wait to cover a defect use huge sleeps (remember polls are better) to cover it and get you stable while the defect is worked on.